# Math.NET Numerics - Matrix<double> from an array of doubles

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, mathnet-numerics

Assuming I have:

`double[] someArray = new [] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23, 24, 31, 32, 33, 34, 41, 42, 43, 44 };`

Is there any out of the box way of creating a 4x4 matrix out of this array without having to split it into 4 arrays myself?

I know it is simple to do this, but I'm exploring how much is ready out of the box.

**EDIT**

Sorry for not being clear (thought title was):

What I'm wondering is if there is out of the box functionality with the Matrix builder in Math.NET Numerics. Something like:

`Matrix<double> someMatrix = DenseMatrix.OfArray(columns: 4, rows: 4, data: someArray);`

Comment: How do values in this array correspond to matrix values? Math.NET Numerics dense matrices use column-major order internally, but other libraries may use row-major or something else completely.

Comment: `someArray` is in column major order, in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at the [documentation](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm), you could use the constructor directly, or the function `OfColumnMajor(int rows, int columns, IEnumerable<double> columnMajor)`, if your data is in column-major order.

The code would look like this:

```
//Using the constructor
Matrix<double> someMatrix = new DenseMatrix(4, 4, someArray)

//Using the static function
Matrix<double> someMatrix = DenseMatrix.OfColumnMajor(4, 4, someArray);
```

If your data is in row-major order, you could split into arrays and use one of the `OfRows` function, or use the constructor and transpose the matrix, as suggested by Christoph.

Comment: Yes, provided the array is in column-major order.

Comment: Yes, otherwise there is no OfRowMajor function, you would have to split into arrays and use OfRows function.

Comment: NB: if the data is in column-major order you can also use the [constructor](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseMatrix.htm#.ctor) directly. This is in fact the most efficient way to create a dense matrix.

Comment: In case of row-major you can still use the constructor (with switched cols/rows dimensions) and then transpose the resulting matrix.

Comment: @ChristophRüegg Thanks for providing with the useful extra info. It was my next question (row-major scenarios)